# Authorization .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have setup cookie authentication in my asp.net core application. I have a login page where the credentials matchup against the active directory. All this works fine.
Now next I want to implement authorization in my application. I have a table of users together with permission against them. For example permission like Reading & Write. When the user is successfully authenticated I want to check for these permissions and show them certain functionality while restricting others. For example, show certain dropdowns for write permission while hiding for reading permission.

What is the best approach to handle this in the .NET Core. 
I have read about adding policy like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("Read", policy => 
                      policy.RequireClaim("Read", "MyCLaim"));
 });
```

Then in my controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

}
```

Where do I get the permissions for logged in user from my database and how to verify if the user has those permissions or not.

Would appreciate inputs.

Comment: The current Recemmended way are [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). When ever you think you need permissions, rethink if you are using the builtin Identity... It is an Identity Server, which says, what your email, phone, age, role is. When thinking about Permission and UserGroups, imho you can drop Identity as such... Recommended reading: [Permissions](http://benjamincollins.com/blog/practical-permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/), [Authentification](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop)

Comment: Will look into this. FYI I am using cookie based authentication together with Active directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I get the permissions for logged in user from my database and
>   how to verify if the user has those permissons or not.

Right after a user is authenticated, you collect user's claims, and store them in Authentication Cookie.

*For example, [SignInAsync](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web.Common/Security/SignInManager.cs#L20) method.*

```
public async Task SignInAsync(User user, IList<string> roleNames)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)
    };

    foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
    }

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "local", "name", "role");
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
      CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
}
```

*FYI: It happens to be that I store them as Role claims. You do not have to follow that route, if you don't want.*

You can then verify the policy inside [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Startup.cs#L85).

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        // Set up policies from claims
        // https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Constants.RoleNames.Administrator, policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .RequireAssertion(context => context.User.HasClaim(
                        ClaimTypes.Role, Constants.RoleNames.Administrator))
                    .Build();
            });
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

[Usage](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Presentation/Asp.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/DashboardController.cs#L8) is same as what you have described.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Few questions: 1) var claims = new List<Claim>
    {  } //So here I make db call to my database and get the logged in user permissions like Read/Write .     2.) What is IList<string> roleNames. How do I get these role and what purpose it solves. I thought we were already getting claims from above steps 3. [Authorize(Policy = "Read")] This attribute is on the controller. Is there some way we can authorize certain features on my application. For example if the user has Read only role then hide certain controls on my view. How can I do that. Thanks

Comment: 1) Yes 2) You have to some how store what user can do in your system. Normally, we solve it by creating separate [role table](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit#database-diagram). 3) Let try to make it works for controller using above 2 steps. Then create a new question about hiding individual control based on Policy.

Comment: After authentication I setup claims. How can I update my claims in my controller afterwards if I have to.

Comment: Claims are stored inside authentication cookie. So if you need to update claims, you will need to recreate the authentication cookie again.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this .  var user = context.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal; var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;  var claim = (from c in user.Claims
                         where c.Type == "MyClaim"
                         select c).Single();

            identity.RemoveClaim(claim);   Would it be fine to look for claim this way and remove the claim

Comment: It just removes Claims inside Principle object which is stored inside current thread. You will need to override the existing authentication cookie value with new one. For example, sign-out first `HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` then sign-in again with new claims `HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);`